# Класс обертка для управления константностью объекта

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, const

У меня есть несколько классов, в которых есть функции `lock()` и `unlock()`, которые управляют переменной класса `bool lock`. Если `lock == true`, то объект становится константным - можно читать данные из класса, а попытка изменить объект вызывает ошибку времени выполнения.

Хочу обобщить данный механизм - написать класс обертку, который аналогично управлял бы хранящемся в нем объектом. Что-то вроде такого:

```
template <typename T>
class locking_type
{
public:
    locking_type() : _value(T{}), _lock(false) {};
    ~locking_type() {};

    void lock() { _lock = true; }
    void unlock() { _lock = false; }

    // if _lock
    //const T& operator()() { return _value; }
    T& operator()() { return _value; }

    operator T() const { return _value; }

private:
    T _value;
    bool _lock;
};
```

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы если `_lock = false` возвращалась обычная ссылка на хранящийся объект, а если `_lock = true` возвращалась бы константная ссылка?

Comment: Возможно сделать +- так как вы хотите с помощью variant. Но я не понимаю то, как и зачем вы хотите это использовать.

Comment: для повышения безопасности. Есть переменные, которые очень часто используются, но их изменение происходит в исключительных случаях (в основном это базовые типы или стандартные контейнеры, например, залочить вектор, и нельзя будет изменить его размер, чтобы не попортить указатели). Хотелось бы отслеживать такие случаи. 
да, была идея использовать variant, или просто написать разных два метода. Но это не совсем удобно.

Comment: Дурацкая идея. Вы хотите провоцировать написание неряшливого кода, который будет находиться в процессе перманентной отладки production

Comment: @avp я чувствовал, что текущая архитектура требует рефакторинга. Вы подтвердили мои сомнения

Answer (score 4):

Вы понимаете, эти `const` обрабатываются не во время выполнения, а во время компиляции. Если `_lock` - это `constexpr`, то можно - через шаблон, например.

Но во время работы программы понятия `const` нет. Поэтому максимум, что можно - отреагировать средствами времени выполнения - например, при `_lock == true` генерировать исключение при вызове неконстантного метода.

Кстати, а как вы себе представляете, что именно должна делать программа, если вдруг что-то, что было неконстантным, вдруг становится таким? И выполняется действие, которое вдруг стало запрещенным?

Comment: В принципе (в *nix), объект можно разместить по  границе page и делать [mprotect](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html). / А вообще, полностью согласен с вами, практического смысла в таких телодвижениях обычно нет.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что const это свойство переменной времени компиляции. Т.к. являюсь новичком в программировании на C++, то подумал, что, возможно, существует механизм для решения подобной задачи, о котором я не знаю.

Comment: Иногда знание таких вещей может сэкономить много времени. Знай бы я как работает aliasing constructor для shared_ptr пару недель назад - сэкономил бы пару  ночей ;)